# How to safely .ToLower().Contains() on possible null property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, .net-core

```
private Expression<Func<ProductDto, bool>> FilterData(ProductRequest searchQuery)
{
    string searchString = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery.SearchString)
           ? searchQuery.SearchString.ToLower()
           : string.Empty;

    return f => ((f.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(searchString))
                || (f.ProductParentName.ToLower().Contains(searchString)));
}
```

Sometimes `ProductName` or `ProductParentName` are null so my application crashes.

I've tried using C# 6.0 feature null conditional operator so I wrote something like this:

```
return f => ((f.ProductName?.ToLower().Contains(searchString))
                    || (f.ProductParentName?.ToLower().Contains(searchString)));
```

But than I got message :

> operator || cannot be applied to operands of type `'bool'` and
>   `'bool?'`

How could I ensure could will execute even if some props are null here?

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: Use the conditional ternary operator: `f.ProductName != null ? f.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(searchString) : false`. Note that I wouldn't expect you to get `null` errors with LINQ to EF or SQL as they are translated into SQL queries which normally pass null through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes ProductName or ProductParentName are null so my application crashes.

Assuming this it to be executed server side and not in memory,

Keep it simple and check for null before apply functions.

```
return f => ((f.ProductName != null && f.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(searchString))
            || (f.ProductParentName != null && f.ProductParentName.ToLower().Contains(searchString)));
```

The framework should be able to translate this to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** It's not possible to use a null-propagating operator from within an expression tree lambda (I couldn't get it to work using `ToLower` either). You could refactor to something like the below using `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to perform a case-insensitive comparison:

```
return f => (f.ProductName != null)
          ? (f.ProductName.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
             || f.ProductParentName.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )
          : false;
```

---

**Original answer**

You could combine this with the [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operator (`??`).

```
return f => ( (f.ProductName?.ToLower().Contains(searchString) ?? false)
           || (f.ProductParentName?.ToLower().Contains(searchString) ?? false));
```

`f.ProductName?.ToLower()` uses the [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) operator (`.?`) which returns `null` when `ProductName` is `null`, so you need to return a default value which is what the null-coalescing operator provides.

Comment: It says expression three lambda may not contain a null propagation operator... But I will try again

Comment: @Roxy'Pro I've updated my answer. I don' think it's possible to use null-coalescing/propagating operator within an expression tree.

Comment: I don't think you can use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` with the `Contains` method.

Comment: @RufusL it's working for me in .net core ([contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.0)). But you're right, doesn't work in .net framework! Question is tagged .net core so should be ok!

Comment: Ah, cool. I did not know that! No need for `ToLower` at all, then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IndexOf` instead of `Contains`, because it provides a comparison type argument, which you can specify to be case-insensitive. This is generally better than calling `ToLower` on the strings (see [this article](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html) for more info):

```
var search = searchQuery.SearchString ?? string.Empty;

return f => 
    f.ProductName?.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1 ||
    f.ProductParentName?.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;
```

You also don't have to do any coalescing if the value is `null`, since the `-1` is treated as a `Nullable<int>` by the compiler, and it will return `false` if the left side is `null`.

Comment: This is the most elegant and straightforward solution. Surprised it did not have any votes.

Answer (score 0):

There are surely lots of ways to solve this problem and my first try didn't work.

Since the returned expression cannot use a local function or the null propogation operator, an old fashioned test might just do:

```
private Expression<Func<ProductDto, bool>> FilterData(ProductRequest searchQuery)
{
    string searchString = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery.SearchString)
           ? searchQuery.SearchString.ToLower()
           : string.Empty;

    return f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)
       || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.ProductName) && f.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(searchString))
       || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.ParentProductName) && f.ParentProductName.ToLower().Contains(searchString));
}
```

I used the same function signature you did, and the compiler seems happy about it, though it definitely looks cluttered.

Be sure to adjust the first part of the `return` to reflect what to do if the search string is empty: the one I used assumes an empty search string matches *everything* - edit to taste.